# Image root issue in laravel in cPanel

Tags: laravel, image, cpanel

Images getting stored in outside public folder and in view, getting called from inside public folder. Everything was working fine in local host. After uploading the project in cpanel i took index.php and htaccess outside public folder. How can i store and call them from same folder? Thank you.

Comment: run command : `php artisan storage:link`

Comment: Who are "them"? Why did you move `index.php`  out of the public folder?

Comment: them means images. followed a tutorial to get rid of 'public' from the url. thank you.

Comment: @Himel the laravel public folder must be your domains root folder. Never move the index.php file...

Comment: after running php artisan storage:link i got this  'The [public/storage] directory has been linked'.

Comment: Yes, now there is a symlink in your public folder that points to the storage folder, so your stored images will load

Comment: @GertB. index.php is in 'public_html'. just outside 'public' folder.

Comment: iIt belongs in the laravel public folder...

Answer (score 0):

When using Laravel all HTTP Requests has to be hit `public` directory. But since you are using cPanel all Requests hit directly `public_html` by default.

You tried to overcome it by moving `index.php` and `.htaccess` files to `public_html` from `public_html/public` and you broke its structure.

If you have the Administrative (eg: root) access on server, you can solve this by editing your Web server (I assume Apache in your case) to point your domain's requests directly to your Laraval application's `public` directory.

Usually every Web site in cPanel have separate config files. Their paths something like this:

`/var/cpanel/userdata/CPANELUSER/WEBSITEDOMAIN.COM` and `/var/cpanel/userdata/CPANELUSER/WEBSITEDOMAIN.COM_SSL`

In this files there is a `documentroot` field, it points to `public_html` directory by default:

`documentroot: /home/CPANELUSER/public_html`

You need to change it and point it to your application's `public` directory;

`documentroot: /home/CPANELUSER/laravel/project/path/public`

After you update both of these files, you need to rebuild your Apache config and restart it;

`/usr/local/cpanel/scripts/rebuildhttpdconf`
`/usr/local/cpanel/scripts/restartsrv_httpd`

If those 2 lines don't work, you can try this 2;

`/scripts/rebuildhttpdconf`
`/scripts/restartsrv_apache`

If everything done well, all HTTP Requests will hit your Laravel application's `public` directory as expected.

After that; if your uploaded files stores in `public` storage, Laravel puts them in to `storage/app/public` and you need a symlink to it from `public` directory.

Laravel creates it when you run

`php artisan storage:link`

Now all your application's requests as `your.domain/storage/bla.jpg` will give a response from `storage/app/public/bla.jpg`

And if you don't have administrative access to server you can check this tutorial: [How to deploy Laravel 8 project on Cpanel shared hosting](https://zestmade.com/blog/how-to-deploy-laravel-on-cpanel/)